# Disable ListBox items

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

As far as I know, there is no way to grey out/disable specific items in the ListBox control?

I want to make a list of surveys that need to be answered, but grey out/disable those that the user has already answered.

Anyone got some advices how I should do this? Or is there some way to do it with ListBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do custom drawing to handle this.  Look up `OwnerDraw`

The typical (and simpler) pattern is just to not include those items in the ListBox.

An alternative would be to use `ListView` in Details view mode.  Then you can modify each item's fore/back colors, font, and more.

Comment: Well, I wanted to make a function for "Show all" and "Show unanswered", but I guess I'll just leave the answered ones out. Anyway, thanks for your answer!