# How can i disable custom item in listbox with vb.net

Tags: .net, winforms

I would like to disable a specific item in a WinForms ListBox. I do not want to remove the item, only disable it.

I've tried the code below, but that didn't work:

```
ListBox1.Items.Item(1).Contains("KG").Enabled = False;
```

Comment: Is this a WPF project, or WinForms? Where are you failing and what have you tried to solve it? Please give us some more relevant information to be able to help you.

Comment: You need to provide a little more context, and possibly some example of your code to help others understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of depends on if this is a WPF project, or a WinForms project. So it would help if you would incorporate this type of information in your question.

For WinForms: this isn't possible by default. Have a look over here: [Disable ListBox items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435537/disable-listbox-items)
For WPF: this is fairly simple. Have a look here: [Disable particular item in the ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520879/disable-particular-item-in-the-listbox?rq=1)

**EDIT**
Since you told us it's WinForms: as I said earlier it's not that simple. By default it's not possible: there is no native Disable/Enable for items in ListBox.
Next to the SO question I linked to before, have a look at this one that creates some custom controls to get the job done: [How To Disable Selected Item In List Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090317/how-to-disable-selected-item-in-list-box).

It's written in C#, but that shouldn't hold you back.

As more people on multiple other questions have already said: the simple solution is to not show the items you don't want your users to select.